# How to add medianet with Prebid and Google Ad Manager

Tags: prebid.js, header-bidding

I am implementing Prebid.js. I am trying to work with Medianet. I keep getting an error response from the Medianet server: `{"ext":{"nbr":"server_err_cfg"}}`.

Support from Media.net hasn't responded yet. Any ideas on what can be the best solution to this? Also, do I need to have `hb_pb` for the key value in DFP (Google Ad Manager) or do I need to setup the line items with hb_pbmedianet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate key values for medianet (hb_pbmedianet) unless you are using sendAllBids configuration with Prebid.

Sounds like the IDs you are passing to the Media.net adapter are incorrect.

I would check them again again and be sure you are passing the right parameters to the ad unit. According to the [Medianet docs](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/bidders/medianet.html), you need a cid and crid, both strings. Make sure these are 100% correct.